# What could we never replace/recreate on another planet what we have on earth

Tags: space, earth, survival

Following the answer from this [link](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-earth-like-planet-outside-the-Solar-System-and-why) and assuming this is the best choice, if we had leave Earth right now and inhabit another world in a different planetary system, what would be the things that we would be forced to take from Earth to such new planets due to dearth in the new planet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most earth-like planet in real life](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19023/most-earth-like-planet-in-real-life)

Comment: Please read the last question in both posts. From which POV do they seem the same to you?

Comment: A suggestion would be to try and formulate the first question in to what you would like to ask. Insted of asking the same question 3 times with different headlines

Comment: I don't know about others but I would definitely being forced to take my space sickness medicine along else I won't last the flight, sleeping pills are good too and also bring some marijuana for entertainment purposes.

Comment: I think if you rephrased your question and instead asked for what was the most important things a colony would need to bring and/or what resources would never be found at a new planet, and limit it to like the top 5 or so.  This might sufficiently narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: But this could be a fantastic & interesting question.

Answer (score 5):

While most resources might or might not exist on other planets (and we could choose one with all the needed resources), there is one thing that couldn't be duplicated.

Another planet have might developed life, and it might even be similar to earths life. It is thinkable in that case that carbohydrates (sugar for instance) may be used as an energy-depot like earth-life uses it. The alien life might even use proteins. But it is pretty unlikely, that the same set of [amino acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid) is used to build these proteins. So we should bring earth plants and animals for food.

To explain it a bit more in detail: Proteins are used throughout earth life forms as basic structural element and for controlling purposes. There are a lot of proteins. Proteins are generally build, by connecting amino acids into a long string and fold it in some way. This way pretty different proteins are created. The genetic information mostly codes this sequence of amino acids in proteins used. 20 amino acids are used in most of earths life to build the proteins. While the set of amino acids needs to fulfil some criteria to have the needed variety, the amino acids used are more or less random. There are other amino acids our bodies could use, but don't. The decision was made early in evolution, as these sequence of amino acids are the main vector of inheritance in the genetic code. That doesn't mean we don't see a bit of [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genetic_codes) on earth. Some very simple life forms use a reduced set of amino acids. Also some life forms use two additional amino acids. These natural differences are small, as they include a change of the genetic coding - and the standard code works. Some alien life form may have developed randomly another standard genetic coding. Researchers have added more than 70 nonstandard amino acids to bacteria. So these amino acids work too. On another world it is likely the set of standard amino acids would differ. So eating alien life forms would leave out some amino acids.

Comment: True and a good point that is often skipped in scifi. Unfortunately the reason it is skipped it is that is rarely relevant, the chances of alien life being anywhere near as productive and edible as terran species with thousand of years of selective breeding for that purpose are small enough that using terran species or genetic engineering is a requirement anyway. But as I said a good point.

Answer (score 2):

Life.  Life from earth and the genes we need to create our food.  Quite likely we are going to a planet without any life on it, and even if there is life, small chance we will find it consumable.